# How can I make it so that the column only calculates data from a certain date?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, formula

I am attempting to get the column to essentially lookup any submissions and only take into account the ones that apply to the numbers in column B. If any of the form submissions match the number in the respective row in Column B then I want it to essentially add the 1 to Column B. This is the formula that I've used but it doesn't seem to be working as I'd hoped it would.

```
=arrayformula(if(isnumber(B2:B150),countifs('Activity Logs'!E4:E,B2:B150,month('Activity Logs'!E4:E),month(edate(today(),-0)),year('Activity Logs'!E4:E),YEAR(edate(today(),-0))),))
```

Here's the spreadsheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1T6TUzySQTLzjMni9ZyDWOFs6YnRqSwtzJ317ilJ0Y0Q/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use in M9:

```
={""; ARRAYFORMULA(IFNA(VLOOKUP($B$10:$B, QUERY(
 FILTER('Activity Logs'!$E$5:$E, MONTH('Activity Logs'!$C$5:$C)=MONTH(M5&1)), 
 "select Col1,count(Col1) group by Col1"), 2, 0)))}
```

[image]

Comment: That worked - and if i wanted it to calculate inputs from two months ago would this be the correct formula: ```={""; ARRAYFORMULA(IFNA(VLOOKUP($B$10:$B, QUERY(
 FILTER('Activity Logs'!$E$4:$E, MONTH('Activity Logs'!$C$4:$C)=MONTH(M5&1)-2), 
 "select Col1,count(Col1) group by Col1"), 2, 0)))}```. I tried that formula but it's not working to calculate December - I'm not sure if it's because that year passed already (I did input a test log for december of last year)

Comment: it would be: `={""; ARRAYFORMULA(IFNA(VLOOKUP($B$10:$B, QUERY(
 FILTER('Activity Logs'!$E$4:$E, MONTH('Activity Logs'!$C$4:$C)=MONTH(I5&1)), 
 "select Col1,count(Col1) group by Col1"), 2, 0)))}`

Comment: M5 is february... thats number 2 month... 2-2=0... but december is month number 12 so thats why it did not work for you